# xpath - How to change the values of nodes returned by xpath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have an array of ids that need replacing from a piece of html.

```
$ids = array(
    '111' => '999', // I need to replace data-note 111 with 999
    '222' => '888' // same 222 needs to be replace with 888
);

$html = '<span data-note="111" data-type="comment">el </span> text <span data-note="222" data-type="comment">el </span>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("//span/@data-note");
foreach($elements as $element){
    echo $element->value . ' '; // echos the correct values
$element->value = 999; // here I want to change the value inside the $html file. how to do this
}
```

My question is how to replace them with the values from the array in the $html variable?

Comment: +1 for providing an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do two things:

- Look up the new value instead of a constant
- Use [`$dom->C14N()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/domnode.c14n.php) to extract the new HTML to a string, or [`$dom->C14N($uri)`](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/domnode.c14nfile.php) which directly saves it to a file.

PHP by default adds html and body elements, so loop over all child nodes of the body tag to reconstruct the output:

```
foreach($elements as $element){
    echo $element->value . ' '; // echos the correct values
$element->value = $ids[$element->value]; // Look up and change to new value
}
$html = '';
foreach($xpath->query('/html/body/* | /html/body/text()') as $element) {
  $html .= $element->C14N();
}
echo $html;
```

Using PHP 5.4+, you will be able to make libxml *not* add html and body elements:

```
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
// [snip]
$html = $dom->C14N();
echo $html;
```

Comment: Works great but it wraps the $html in html and body tags. how to avoid this?

Comment: I've also noticed it works with $html = $dom->saveHtml(); but wraps it in extra tags

Comment: Too bad. You will have to loop over all results of the body element and put together the result again.

Comment: If your PHP is new enough, there's a better way, I updated my answer.